# Solve $iz=\overline{z}$ and $\frac{z}{i}=\overline{z}$, with $z = x+yi$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Note: These are two separate equations, not a system.

I tried:

$$iz=\overline{z} \Leftrightarrow \\
i(x+yi)=x-yi \Leftrightarrow \\
xi-y=x-yi \Leftrightarrow \\
x+y=xi+yi \Leftrightarrow \\
???$$

I can see that one is the other with the x and y coordinates swapped and so for them to be equal I guess the answer would be a line which the x and y coordinates are the same, or $\arg=-\pi/4 \lor \arg=\pi/4$.

My book states the solution is just $\arg=-\pi/4$. Why's that? And how do I continue the equation?

As for the second one:

$$\frac{z}{i}=\overline{z}\Leftrightarrow \\
\frac{x+yi}{i}=x-yi \Leftrightarrow \\
\frac{(x+yi)\cdot-i}{i\cdot -i} = x-yi \Leftrightarrow \\
-(xi-y)=x-yi \Leftrightarrow \\
-xi+y = x-yi \Leftrightarrow \\$$

So here x and y get swapped and there is a reflection of $\pi$ radians, so I would assume the same as above, but my book states that the solution is $\arg=\pi/4$. Why?

Also, I always get confused when solving this kind of equations. I never really know when to stop solving them until the solution is clear and I find these a bit tricky to visualize, so if you have any advice on these please do share.

Comment: `I find these a bit tricky to visualize` First one $iz = \bar z$ for example means that $z$ rotated $\pi / 2$ counterclockwise around the origin  is the same as $z$ reflected across the real axis. Geometrically, this can be shown to happen iff $\,z\,$ lies on the secondary bisector of the axes $\,y=-x\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Why the secondary one only and not both?

Comment: Take a point in the first quadrant for example. If you rotate it $\pi /2$ counterclockwise it will land in the second quadrant. If you reflect it across the real axis it will land in the fourth quadrant. Those two points cannot coincide, therefore no point in the first quadrant can satisfy $iz=\bar z\,$. Same goes for the third quadrant.

Comment: @dxiv Probably a silly question, but why can't they coincide?

Comment: The second quadrant is above of the real axis and left of the imaginary one. The fourth quadrant is below the real axis and to the right of the imaginary one. They have no points in common. Equivalently, the second quadrant is $\pi / 2 \lt \arg z \lt \pi\,$, while the fourth quadrant is $-\pi/2 \lt \arg z \lt 0\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry, I still don't understand...

Comment: For $z$ in the first quadrant, $iz$ is in the second quadrant, and $\bar z$ in the fourth quadrant. But the second and fourth quadrants have no points in common, so necessarily $i z \ne \bar z\,$. Therefore the first bisector $y=x$ which crosses the first quadrant cannot contain points $z$ such that $i z = \bar z\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If,

$$x+y=(x+y)i$$

Then,

$$(x+y)-i(x+y)=0$$

$$(x+y)(1-i)=0$$

So it follows,

$$x+y=0$$

$$y=-x$$

In polar this is $\theta=-\frac{\pi}{4}$ or equally as well $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}$. The other is similar. But the convention is to take the angle $\in (-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: But $-\dfrac\pi4$ and $\dfrac{3\pi}4$ are not equal, right?

Comment: Ok I got the first one as for the second one I got as far as $-i(x+yi)=x-yi \Leftrightarrow -i=\frac{x-yi}{x+yi}$. What do I do next?

Comment: I forgot that it is a convention to keep $arg (z) \in [-\pi,pi]$.

Comment: Mark, try to get everything with $i$ on one side and everything without on the other @MarkRead

Comment: I got $-(xi-yi)=(x-y)$. Does this mean that the negative y coordinate and the x coordinate are equal? Then the answer would be $\arg=-\pi/4$?

Comment: @Mark, Use the definition of atan2 from my answer.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I have to solve this analitically.

Comment: If $-i(x-y)=(x-y)$ then $(x-y)+i(x-y)=0$ hence $(1+i)(x-y)=0$ and $x-y=0$. So we conclude $x=y$. @MarkRead

Comment: Ah I see, and so the answer is $\arg=\pi/4 \lor \arg=5\pi/4$. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, usually though we restrict it to the principal value which in some texts is between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. Excluding $-\pi$ and including $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x+y=i(x+y)\iff(1-i)(x+y)=0\implies x+y=0$$

Now use atan2(  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

Comment: You forgot to consider the 2nd equation $\frac{z}{i}=\overline{z}$

Comment: @Display, I thought them to be independent. However, if the equations are related, the problem can be solved in the same line

Comment: I thought that this was a system of equations. OP should update answer to state whether it's a system or 2 separate equations.

Comment: @Displayname It's 2 separate ones. I'll edit.

Comment: @Display, They ought to be independent as   OP has already reached at the arg based on the first equation only.

Answer (score 0):

Given $iz=\overline{z}$ and $\frac{z}{i}=\overline{z}$, $\overline{z}=i(i\overline{z})=-\overline{z}$, so $\overline{z}=0$, which means $z=0$.

Edit: These are actually 2 separate equations. The solution to the 1st is $x+y=0$, or $\theta=\frac{-\pi}{4}$ while the solution to the latter is $x-y=0$, or $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$